# How does the controller pick the correct action when using polymorphism?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just realized that something that I've been using for quite many years shouldn't work! Consider the following polymorphism of an action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() { ... }

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult MyAction(String input) { ... }
```

It's obvious that when we come in using *GET*, only the first one remains as a valid candidate, because the attribute filters out the latter. Hence, it's unequivocal and everybody's happy. However, what if we jump into the code using *POST*?

At first glance, one is prone to figure that since the first method is a more general action, the latter is more rational to be intended for usage in this particular case "*to cover the specials*", so to speak. But that's the human logic. I doubt that the server reasons like that, though.

I've checked through the routings and other files I could find in a project but as far I could see, there's some black magic involved.   :)

So my question is this: how does the framework know what to pick?

A follow-up question is begged to be whether it varies across the versions of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework indeed reasons as you do: the latter action is chosen because it is considered more specific. I haven't checked every release, but I don't think this behaviour has changed since the introduction of the `HttpPostAttribute`.

However, I have downloaded the ASP.NET MVC source code several times over time, and I can see that the implementation has indeed changed somewhat. At one point, the relevant part of the source code in the `RunSelectionFilters` method of `ActionMethodSelector` looked like this:

```csharp
// if a matching action method had a selection attribute, consider it more 
// specific than a matching action method without a selection attribute
return (matchesWithSelectionAttributes.Count > 0) 
  ? matchesWithSelectionAttributes 
  : matchesWithoutSelectionAttributes;
```

This is not the current implementation, though. In [the source code on codeplex right now](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), the implementation is a bit more complex, but the behaviour is the same, cf. the comments inside `RunSelectionFilters(...)` of `ActionMethodSelectorBase.cs`:

```csharp
//Methods with valid selection attributes override all others.
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest reading Phil Haack's [How a Method Becomes An Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx/), which should answer your question.  Quoting some important parts:

> #### ActionSelectionAttribute
>
> Once we’ve identified all methods of the Controller class that match the current action name, we need to whittle the list down further by looking at all instances of the ActionSelectionAttribute applied to the methods in the list.
>
> This attribute is an abstract base class for attributes which provide fine grained control over which requests an action method can respond to. The API for this method is quite simple and consists of a single method.

```
public abstract class ActionSelectionAttribute : Attribute
{
  public abstract bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext,
      MethodInfo methodInfo);
}
```

Then a little further down:

> At the end, we should be left with one method in the list, which the invoker then invokes. If more than one method can handle the current request, the invoker throws an exception indicating the problem. If no method can handle the request, the invoker calls HandleUnknownAction() on the controller.
>
> The ASP.NET MVC framework includes one implementation of this base attribute, the AcceptVerbsAttribute.

The article goes on to explain how this process works with `AcceptVerbsAttribute`, showing an example comparable with yours.

Comment: First of all - thanks for a great link. I've read the article you referred to and, while well written, it doesn't really answer my question (possibly because I've missed it). In fact, he mentions that an exception will be thrown if multiple methods are left after the filtration of the candidates (which is untrue due to the attributes). Then, he presents an example with attributes on **both** polymorph methods (which is a very clear way that I'd advocate) **but** it doesn't addresses my question on the "*feels right*"-like choice of the attributeless case. What did I miss?

Comment: I see what you mean now, but he's right in that if two actions are left it throws an exception: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException.  I read the article a second time, after your comment, and you're right in that he doesn't answer your question.  However, actions marked with `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`s will be prioritised before any that aren't decorated.  That attribute is simply a filter, so an undecorated method will accept both `GET` and `POST`, but will not be selected before a method that is decorated with `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`s, which can handle the current request.

Comment: @KonradViltersten In fact, don't take my word for it, you can see the relevant code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1073764/729541).

Comment: +1 Ah, **there** it was. That one was right on the spot what I was curious about. There's a lot of automagical stuff in MVC and one doesn't realize it until doing something unusually smart (or dumb - the line between these is hair-fine). Having more time on my hands the last few days I started to laborate with different approaches not following the old and proven ways - just to test the limits. Thanks!

Comment: @KonradViltersten I agree with you.  If anything, the most difficult part usually seems to consist of finding the name of the right type that's involved.  Once you have that, everything else is pretty straightforward to figure out.  Glad it helped anyway.